# Не могу подключить CSS к файлу single.php (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть файл  - **single.php:**

```js
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php the_post(); ?>

<main class="Main_Content"> 
  
<article class="Text_Main_Block"> 
<h1 class ="first_title"> <?php the_title(); ?> </h1>
<br>
<?php the_content(); ?>

</article>
  
</main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**И functions.php:**
Оба этих файла лежат в wp-content/themes/My-theme

Почему я не могу подключить два стиля только к базовому шаблону **постов(single.php)?**
**Конструкцию подключения я пометил комментарием со звездочками**

```js
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Join_CSS' );
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_setup' );
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');

function theme_setup(){
add_theme_support('custom-logo');       
add_theme_support('title-tag'); 
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');   
}

function Join_CSS() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'main_style', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/style.css',
[], '1.1', 'all');
wp_enqueue_style( 'main_media', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/media.css',
[], '1.1', 'all');

 
// *************** ПОЧЕМУ ЭТО УСЛОВИЕ НЕ РАБОТАЕТ? ***************

if ( is_page_template( '/single.php' ) ) {  
wp_enqueue_style( 'post', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/Post/post_page.css',
[], '1.0', 'all');

wp_enqueue_style( 'post-media', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/Post/post_page_media.css',
[], '1.0', 'all');
}
 // *************** КОНЕЦ УСЛОВИЯ ***************
}
```

Comment: Потому что надо использовать is_single().

Comment: Прочитал про is_single() там сказано, что это проверяет содержимое записи на строки и id. Я не могу понять как это работает. Не могли бы вы пожалуйста привести пример is_single() с моими подключаемыми двумя стилями.

Answer (score 0):

if ( is_single()) {
wp_enqueue_style( 'post', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/Post/post_page.css',
[], '1.0', 'all');

wp_enqueue_style( 'post-media', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/Post/post_page_media.css',
[], '1.0', 'all');
}